# The number must be divisible by 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> How many five-digit numbers can be formed from the digits 0, 1, 2, 3,
>   4, and 5, if no digits can repeat and the number must be divisible by
>   4?

To solve this question I have guessed that the last digit could be 0, 2 or 4.

Therefore we can have 3 ways for the fifth position.

The rest of the position can be arrange like this:

$4 \times 3\times 2 \times 1 \times3 $ the first position can be arranged by 4 ways because we placed the 0 in the first position to have five digit.

But the answer is not identical to the real one. Can you help regarding this?

Comment: More precise : A number is divisible by $4$, if and only if the last two digits form a number divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First note that a number is divisible by 4 if and only if its two last 
>   digits is divisible by 4, or more precisely,
>   $$4|...dcba\Leftrightarrow 4|ba$$
>   Then all we have to do is count how many numbers we can write is this way,
>   for exemple:
>   we have $$4\times3\times2\times1 : abcd04 \mbox{ ( ending in } 04)\\4\times3\times2\times1 : abcd40 \mbox{ ( ending in } 40)$$
>   Now not that zero cannot be the first digit of such number so, for example
>   we have
>   $$3\times3\times2\times1 : abcd12 \mbox{ ( ending in } 12)$$
>   with this in mind you have to count all possible cases.